# Export results from split and lapply to a csv or Excel file

Tags: r, split, lapply

I'm using the `split()` and `lapply` functions to run Mann Kendall trend tests in bulk. In the code below, `split()` separates the results (ConcLow) by Analyte (water quality parameter). Then lapply runs the `MannKendall` and `summary` for each. The output goes to the console (example shown below code), but I'd like it to go into an Excel or cvs document so I can work with it. Ideally the Excel document would have the analyte (TOC for example) in the first column, then end column = tau value, 3rd column = pvalue. Then the next tab or following columns would display results from the `summary`  function. Any assistance you can provide is greatly appreciated! I'm quite new to R.

`mk.analyte <- split(BarkTop$ConcLow, BarkTop$Analyte)
lapply(mk.analyte, MannKendall)
lapply(mk.analyte, summary)`

Output for each analyte looks like this (abbreviated here, but it's a long list):

```
$TOC
tau = 0.0108, 2-sided pvalue =0.8081

$TOC
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.378   2.054   2.255   2.434   2.600   4.530
```

Data look like this:

```
Date        Location         Analyte   ConcLow   Units
  5/8/2000  Barker Res.   Hardness    3.34  mg/L (as CaCO3)
11/24/2000  Barker Res.   Hardness    9.47  mg/L (as CaCO3)
 6/12/2001  Barker Res.   Hardness     1.4  mg/L (as CaCO3)
12/29/2001  Barker Res.   Hardness    21.9  mg/L (as CaCO3)
 7/17/2002  Barker Res.   Fe (diss      81  ug/L
  2/2/2003  Barker Res.   Fe (diss      90  ug/L
 8/21/2003  Barker Res.   Fe (diss    0.08  ug/L
  3/8/2004  Barker Res.   Fe (diss  15.748  ug/L
 9/24/2004  Barker Res.   TSS          6.2  mg/L
 4/12/2005  Barker Res.   TSS            8  mg/L
10/29/2005  Barker Res.   TSS           10  mg/L
```

Comment: Would you prefer to export the data in the `summary()` output format, or would it be more useful if it was in a table with columns for each value, and a row for each list element?

Comment: @Mako212 - thanks for the reply! A table would be preferred

Comment: Can you give a sample dataset?

Comment: @DJV - I tried copying a small table of my data in, but it's not working correctly. Just shows a string of numbers and text. How do I enter a table of data into my question?

Comment: You can use `dput(data.frame/list here)`

Comment: @DJV - not sure how to use that function, but I was able to copy in a text file of the data in my question above

Answer (score 0):

In my own opinion, I would use the `tidyverse`, as it is easier to read.

## Short way:

```
#Sample data
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(
  Location = replicate(1000, sample(letters[1:15], 1)), 
  Analyte = replicate(1000, sample(c("Hardness", "TSS", "Fe"), 1)), 
  ConcLow = runif(1000, 1, 30))

#Soltion
df %>% 
  nest(-Location, -Analyte) %>% 
  mutate(
    mannKendall = purrr::map(data, function(x) { 
      broom::tidy(Kendall::MannKendall(x$ConcLow))}), 
    sumData = purrr::map(data, function(x) { 
      broom::tidy(summary(x$ConcLow))})) %>% 
  select(-data)  %>% 
  unnest(mannKendall, sumData) %>% 
  write_excel_csv(path = "mydata.xls")

#How the table looks like: 
# A tibble: 45 x 13
   Location Analyte statistic p.value kendall_score denominator var_kendall_sco~ minimum    q1 median
   <fct>    <fct>       <dbl>   <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>            <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 n        Fe        0.264    0.0907            61        231.            1258.    1.38 14.4    20.6
 2 o        Hardne~   0.0870   0.568             24        276.            1625.    2.02  9.52   18.3
 3 e        Fe       -0.108    0.499            -25        231.            1258.    1.14  9.24   15.9
 4 m        TSS      -0.00654  1                 -1        153              697     2.19  5.89   10.4
 5 j        TSS      -0.158    0.363            -27        171.             817     1.20  6.44   12.8
 6 h        Hardne~   0.0909   0.466             48        528             4165.    4.28 11.1    19.4
 7 l        TSS      -0.0526   0.780             -9        171.             817     5.39 12.5    21.1
 8 c        Fe       -0.0736   0.652            -17        231.            1258.    1.63  5.87   10.6
 9 j        Hardne~   0.415    0.0143            71        171.             817     4.50 11.7    15.4
10 k        Fe       -0.146    0.342            -37        253.            1434.    2.68 12.3    15.4
# ... with 35 more rows, and 3 more variables: mean <dbl>, q3 <dbl>, maximum <dbl>
```

## Long way

It's a bit backwards but you can do something below. 
Please note that I used subset from the mtcars dataset for my solution.

```
require(tidyverse)

df <- mtcars %>% 
  select(cyl, disp)

wilx <- df %>% 
  split(.$cyl) %>% 
  map(function(x) {broom::tidy(wilcox.test(x$disp, paired = FALSE,
                                           exact = FALSE))})


sumData <- df %>% 
  split(.$cyl) %>% 
  map(function(x) {summary(x$disp)})


for (i in 1:length(wilx)) { 

  write_excel_csv(as.data.frame(wilx[i]), path = paste0(getwd(), "/wilx", i, ".xls"))
  write_excel_csv(as.data.frame(unlist(sumData[i])), path = paste0(getwd(), "/sumData", i, ".xls"))

}
```

Comment: I'm trying your second code this morning and am getting an error with "write_excel_csv" saying it can't find the function. I couldn't find a package for it either. Is that a function you created elsewhere?

Comment: My bad. Please see my edit. It's loaded with `tidyverse` but it part of `readr` package.

Comment: loading the readr package made your example work. Thank you. But your example runs the Wilcox test and I'm running the MannKendall test. Is it possible to convert your write_excel_cvs function to my data (see example in question) with the lapply method of running the Mann Kendall? Thank you for helping

Comment: I wasn't able to find your function so I used the base R. In he help for '?wilcox.test', you can see that it actually supports mann also. Anyhow, you can replace it with a function of your choice :)

Comment: sorry I may be missing something, but I can't seem to get it to do what I need. I'm working with a dataset that is different from the mtcars dataset because I have ~20 analytes and ~15 sites (hence I needed to first use the split function to create lists of analytes and associated results for each site). In your code example, where would I use my list "mk.BarkTop" vs the dataframe "BarkTop"?